# CSVHELPER Conditionally ignore writing fields when values null or empty

Tags: c#, .net, csv, .net-core, csvhelper

Im currently writing a flattened DTO object to CSV using the csvhelper's csvwriter. Is there a way to conditionally ignore certain fields if they havent yet been initialised or are null in the mapper ? I see the ignore flag takes a boolean , but how would i get access to the field in question to test for this.

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere but have searched both teh github issues aswell as stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer for me, was to pass in a collection of fields/columns to ignore into the mapper. This involved me checking the data collection for any empty values on all rows, if so then i can omit that column completely. Then i pass this requiredFields collection into the mapper like so .

```
public sealed class ApplicationCsvWriterMap : ClassMap<ApplicationDto>
{
    public ApplicationCsvWriterMap(List<string> requiredFields)
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(1).Name("AppId").Ignore(!requiredFields.Contains("id"));
        Map(m => m.Status.Text).Index(2).Name("Status").Ignore(!requiredFields.Contains("status"));
        Map(m => m.ApplicationTimestamp).Index(3).Ignore(!requiredFields.Contains("applicationTimestamp"));
        Map(m => m.LastModified).Index(4).Ignore(!requiredFields.Contains("lastModified"));
```

Then I can setup the mapper like so , passing in the requiredFields collection like so

```
  else if (results.Data is List<Application> applications)
            {
                csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new ApplicationCsvWriterMap(results.RequiredFields));
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(_dtoMapper.MapApplications(applications));
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was a little bit confused by the question, because Ignore is all or nothing.  You can't ignore a field line by line.  You either include the field or you don't. You could ignore a field if say all of the records had a null or empty value for a particular member variable.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    var records = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "" }, new Foo { Id = 2 } };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
    {        
        var shouldIgnoreName = records.All(foo => string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo.Name));

        var classMap = new DefaultClassMap<Foo>();
        classMap.AutoMap();
        classMap.Map(m => m.Name).Ignore(shouldIgnoreName);

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(classMap);
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```